# Using different speed in switch ports?

Tags: switch

Is it legal to use different Ethernet speed in the different ports of a network switch ?

For example, one port will be connected to a PC in 1G, and another port connected to another PC in 100M ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it legal to use different Ethernet speed in the different ports of a network switch ?

Absolutely - it's even good practice to have a faster uplink port than the downlinks. That way, a 100M switch with a gigabit uplink can support ten 100M streams at the same time, provided the stream sources have enough bandwidth.

Comment: But what if downlink is faster than uplink ? Will it react to a "ping" ?

Comment: Slow uplinks limit the overall downlink capability - a 100M uplink can feed 10 simultaneous streams only at 10M each, regardless of the downlink speeds. The fast ports always need to connect to the most used data sources/sinks - uplinks, servers, ... A `ping` uses only very little bandwidth, so unless a link is thoroughly congested, you won't see a thing.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's legal.  The Internet police will not arrest you.

But you may have a problem if the 1G PC sends a lot of frames to the 100M PC. Because of the speed mismatch, the switch has to buffer the frame until the slower PC can receive it.  Switches, especially inexpensive ones, do not have much buffer memory, so you may end up with dropped frames, causing retransmissions.

Comment: Of course, one could argue that smaller buffers that cause retransmissions sooner will adjust the TCP window sooner and reduce the speed of the session more quickly, possibly reducing the number of total retransmissions. That is of course assuming TCP; if you are talking UDP there may be no retranmissions, simply lost data.